# SPLADE with Laravel - How to create a dynamic cascading category/sub-category select(s)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

This is a classic, but I'm using the amazing SPLADE from slade.dev, and can't get it to work. (How is SPLADE not a tag on stackoverflow yet?)

Use case: The user selects a main category, and then only the sub-categories of that category must show in the sub-categories for him to select from.

In the controller:

```
 $categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->orderBy('name')->pluck('name', 'id');
```

In the blade:

```
<x-splade-select :options="$categories" label="Category" name="category_id" />
                <x-splade-select :options="$subcategories" label="Sub-category" name="subcategory_id" remote-url="/getSubcategories/${form.categoryId}" />
```

getSubcategories is an API that retrieves the subcategories for a given $category_id:

```
$subcategories = Category::whereNotNull('parent_id')->where('parent_id', $category_id)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

${form.categoryId} in the blade above is not right. How do I retrieve the current form's category_id to send to the API?

Answer (score 0):

I used to deal with this for my project as well.
My solution:

- Get all main category
- Get all sub category (add class attribute into sub category html)
- Create js handle main category option:selected to show/hide sub category by class name.

Note: For litle category :)

**To create a dynamic cascading category/sub-category select using SPLADE in Laravel, you can follow these steps:**

1. Create the database table for your categories and sub-categories. For example, you can create a categories table with the following fields:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Note the parent_id field, which will store the ID of the parent category for sub-categories.

2. Create a model for your categories and sub-categories. For example:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

3. Create a controller method to fetch the sub-categories for a given category. For example:

```
public function getSubCategories($id)
{
    $subCategories = Category::where('parent_id', $id)->get();
    return response()->json($subCategories);
}
```

This method will return the sub-categories for the category with the given ID in JSON format.

4. Create a view with two select inputs, one for the category and one for the sub-category:

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="">Select a category</option>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
    <option value="">Select a sub-category</option>
</select>
```

Note that the sub-category select input is initially empty.

5. Add JavaScript code to fetch the sub-categories for the selected category and populate the sub-category select input. For example:

```
$('#category').change(function() {
    var categoryId = $(this).val();
    if(categoryId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/categories/' + categoryId + '/subcategories',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#subcategory').empty();
                $('#subcategory').append($('<option>').text('Select a sub-category'));
                $.each(data, function(index, subCategory) {
                    $('#subcategory').append($('<option>').text(subCategory.name).attr('value', subCategory.id));
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#subcategory').empty();
        $('#subcategory').append($('<option>').text('Select a sub-category'));
    }
});
```

This code will send an AJAX request to the getSubCategories method in your controller when the category select input is changed. It will then populate the sub-category select input with the returned sub-categories.

Comment: Thanks. For Splade, I understand that the script is a not the standard JS, there's a bit of VUE thrown in. Could you share you code please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

In blade:

```
 <x-splade-select :options="$categories" label="Category:" name="category_id" />
 <x-splade-select label="Sub-category" name="subcategory_id" remote-url="`/api/getSubcategories/${form.category_id}`" select-first-remote-option />
```

Where $categories is passed from the controller:

```
 $categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')->where('active', 1)->orderBy('name')->pluck('name', 'id');
```

and the api returns $subcategories as follows:

```
 public function getSubcategories(int $category_id = NULL) //Request $request
    {
        $subcategories = NULL;

        if ($category_id) {
            $subcategories = Category::whereNotNull('parent_id')
                ->where('parent_id', $category_id)
                ->where('active', 1)
                // ->orderBy('name') //pluck ignores it anyway
                ->pluck('name', 'id');
        } else {
            $subcategories = Category::whereNotNull('parent_id')
                ->where('active', 1)
                // ->orderBy('name') //pluck ignores it anyway
                ->pluck('name', 'id');
        }

        return $subcategories;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It has worked for me as follows:

Controller:

```
    public function create()
    {
        $gran_categorias = GranCategoria::pluck('nombre', 'id');
        $data = ['gran_categorias' => $gran_categorias];
        return view('admin/subcategorias/create', $data);
    }

    public function leerCategorias($id = null) {
        if(!$id) return;

        $gc = GranCategoria::where('gran_categoria.id',$id)
            ->join('categorias','categorias.gran_categoria_id','=','gran_categoria.id')
            ->pluck('categorias.nombre','categorias.id');
        return $gc;
    }
```

create.blade.php:

```
<x-splade-form :action="route('subcategorias.store')">
    <x-splade-select name="gran_categoria_id" label="Gran Categoría" :options="$gran_categorias" />
    <x-splade-select name="categoria_id" label="Categoría" remote-url="`/api/gran-categoria/leer-categorias/${form.gran_categoria_id}`" />
    <x-splade-input name="nombre" label="Nombre" />
    <div class=flex>
        <x-splade-submit label="Grabar Subcategoría" class="mt-2 text-white bg-pink-500 hover:bg-pink-600" />
        <div class="mt-4">
            <Link href="{{ route('subcategorias.index') }}" class="ml-2 p-2.5 rounded text-white bg-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-600">Cancelar</Link>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-splade-form>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.